# Java: sum all elements of triangles formed above and below main diagonal

Tags: java, matrix

I have to sum each triangle formed above and below main diagonal in a quadratic matrix, and then subtract one above from the one below, for instance if I have a matrix like:

[image]

I want to calculate:

First triangle : 4 - 4 = 0

Second triangle : ( 4 + 4 + 5 ) - ( 4 + 3 + 1 ) = 6

Third triangle : ( 4 + 4 + 5 + 1 + 3 + 3 ) - (  4 + 3 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 5) = 4

So far I came up with this, and it will calculate all elements of triangles below and above the diagonal.

> I don't know **how to do it for each triangle formed**, and this is my question

```
   public static void main(String...args) {

       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Enter rows/cols : ");    //rows and 
      columns in matrix must be same.
       int rows = scanner.nextInt();
       int columns=rows;
       int[][] matrix = new int[rows][rows];

       System.out.println("Elements of matrix :");
       for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
              for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                    matrix[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
              }
       }

       //Logic to calculate sum of elements above diagonal.
       int sum=0;
       for (int j = 1; j < columns; j++) {
              for (int i=j-1 ; i>=0 ; i--) {
                    sum= sum + matrix[i][j];
              }

       }

       int sumBelow=0;
       for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++) {
              for (int j=i-1 ; j>=0 ; j--) {
                    sumBelow= sumBelow+ matrix[i][j];
              }

       }

       System.out.println("\Matrix is : ");
       for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
              for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                    System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
              }
              System.out.println();
       }

       System.out.println("sum above: "+sum);
       System.out.println("suma below: " + sumBelow );

       int subtract;
       if(sum > sumBelow) {
           razlika = sum - sumBelow;
           System.out.println("Subtracted: " + subtract);
       }else {
           subtract= sumBelow- sum;
           System.out.println("Subtracted: " + subtract);

       }



}
```

What I get is...

[image]

*Please note that I can't use anything but plain arrays, no predefined methods, wrappers or anything.*

Comment: I know, I am helping someone for their programming classes, and the person can't use anything but plain arrays and loops, I am aware of the complexity it carries though.

Comment: If you always get a matrix of the same size the calculations are pretty trivial. Or am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean, in the original task matrix should be populated randomly. I simplified it though just to grasp on the logic.

Comment: If I was unclear don't be bothered to ask for clarification.

Comment: Well yes. of course.

Comment: I already did that, and it is not what I need, take a look at my question one more time.

Comment: Breaking your problem down, you need to be able to: 1. Work out the various triangles needed, 2. Calculate the sum of a specific triangle, 3. Perform some simple subtraction. Please narrow your question down to the MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for just the problem you are having. Please also show what you have tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: I thought I was clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a matrix indexed by (row, col) pair consider the value of `col-row` difference:

```
     0  1  2  3  4
   -------------
0 |  0  1  2  3  4
1 | -1  0  1  2  3
2 | -2 -1  0  1  2
3 | -3 -2 -1  0  1
4 | -4 -3 -2 -1  0
```

Note how the values of `(col-row)` above the main diagonal are all above a certain positive number, and below a certain negative number for cells below the main diagonal.

You can use this property of the indexes to add up values below or above the corresponding diagonal:

```
int addUp(int[][] matrix, int N, int diag) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int row = 0 ; row != N ; row++) {
        for (int col = 0 ; col != N ; col++) {
            int d = col-row;
            if (d >= diag || d <= -diag) {
                sum += matrix[row][col];
            }
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

The call to compute the sum of elements above and below the second diagonals would look like this:

```
int res = addUp(matrix, 5, 2);
```

where `5` is the length of the side of the matrix, and `2` is the second diagonal counting from the middle.